# How to replace string pattern by one character of length of matching substring length?

Tags: java, regex

My attempt:

```
StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=.)(.*?)(?=@)");
Matcher m = emailPattern.matcher("abc123@gmail.com");
while(m.find()){
  m.appendReplacement(bf, "*");
}
return bf.toString();
```

The problem is this code returns "a*@gmail.com", but I want it to return "a*****@gmail.com" where the number of "*" is the number of replaced characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the pattern you could call this instead:

```java
String obfuscate = emailPattern.matcher(email).replaceAll(
    m -> "*".repeat(m.group().length()));
```

(String.repeat from Java 11, this Matcher.replaceAll from Java 9)

Using earlier versions of Java:

```java
while(m.find()) {
    char[] replace = new char[m.group().length()];
    Arrays.fill(replace, '*');
    m.appendReplacement(bf, new String(replace));
}
m.appendTail(bf);
```

Comment: Is there a same way in String.replaceAll?

Comment: Edited to include alternative way